# Generating ad from ad server

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, advertisement-server

*School project*. At this moment I generate ad from database by running ajax JS request to servlet when document is loaded and append parsed data to conrete div element. Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say "yes". Because we're talking about ads, there are two very good things about this approach.

1. It's asynchronous a.k.a., "non-blocking". Users will not be waiting around for ad content as a prerequisite for using the core features of the site.
2. It keeps the ad content out of the server response that will be indexed by search engines.

I'd advise making sure that your final setup is truly "non-blocking" for users; they don't wait needlessly for ad content. Ensuring the ad calls happen after the page load event.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.